# El método delete() de un modelo en Django no se ejecuta

Tags: django, django-models

Estoy sobre escribiendo el método `delete()` de mi modelo para que ejecute una acción antes de desaparecer.

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    print('ejecutando metodo delete')

    producto_detallado = ProductoDetallado.objects.get(id=self.producto_detallado.id)

    # El eliminado de producto venta incrementa el numero de unidades, a el numero de productos disponibles
    producto_detallado.unidades_disponibles += self.unidades_vendidas
    producto_detallado.save()

    super(ProductoVenta, self).delete()
```

Pero al borrar un objeto `ProductoVenta` no esta realizando la acción esperada.

Puse un `prin()` para poder ver en la consola si se esta ejecutando, pero efectivamente no tengo ningún mensaje allí.

Comment: Tal vez lo estés borrando desde un queryset y eso hace que no pase por ese método. En todo caso la mejor solución es usar señales (Signals) para cuando un objeto se elimine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te comentaba, lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar señales (signals). Es más seguro que estar sobreescribiendo los métodos.

Para tu caso, tendrías que definir una señal para cuando se borra una instancia de tu modelo `ProductoVenta`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_delete, sender=ProductoVenta)
def producto_venta_delete_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    producto_detallado = ProductoDetallado.objects.get(id=instance.producto_detallado.id)

    # El eliminado de producto venta incrementa el numero de unidades, a el numero de productos disponibles
    producto_detallado.unidades_disponibles += instance.unidades_vendidas
    producto_detallado.save()
```

Esta función o handler solo será llamada cuando alguna instancia del modelo `ProductoVenta` sea eliminada, ya sea cuando uses el `delete()` del modelo o el `delete()` de un queryset.